# Can't connect to Memgraph Lab on port 3000

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm facing an issue with Memgraph Lab. I can't launch it through https://localhost:3000. I've been using it successfully with Docker some time ago. Yesterday I pulled the new Memgraph 2.10 and I can't connect now. I run Memgraph with `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph`. I can access it with the desktop version of Memgraph Lab.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the port? You look at port 3000 in the URL but you specify another port in Docker command.

Comment: It could be. I'll take another look. I'm having some problems with port 3000 across all my computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with Docker, Memgraph and port 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76927691/problems-with-docker-memgraph-and-port-3000)

Comment: @ElwoodKharson it looks like you created another question for the same problem, I think you should consider merging them.

Comment: It is a similar problem, but not quite the same. In this case I used the wrong image file, the one that  has no Lab. Puling the right image did solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is due to the Docker image you're using. Image `memgraph/memgraph` includes the basic MemgraphDB, meaning you can connect to your instance and use the desktop version of Memgraph Lab.

If you wish to access Memgraph Lab on your `localhost:3000`, try using the `memgraph/memgraph-platform` image and don't forget to expose the port 3000. Your Docker command would then look something like this:

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 memgraph/memgraph-platform
```