# Problems with Docker, Memgraph and port 3000

Tags: memgraphdb

I've tried to run Memgraph Platform using `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform` but I got this output

```
Unable to find image 'memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from memgraph/memgraph-platform
9a9e034800a1: Already exists
f8ad8b2f3aca: Pull complete
24acfa8eab9e: Pull complete
604da11ccbd5: Pull complete
822db1fb53fe: Pull complete
1177de613bdb: Pull complete
f29aba057d8e: Pull complete
dbcbbda98e34: Pull complete
d5587c4e49ad: Pull complete
f9dc7de81bce: Pull complete
803e8cab3295: Pull complete
cca3521c753a: Pull complete
779a5eeab33a: Pull complete
230d64e496e3: Pull complete
9262fac6c515: Pull complete
01801d25f88f: Pull complete
7a4442099e0e: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:54b0c8c15a66f8b9249dc39171508ed6b70df8cf6f3b3e121274aec7e7757d17
Status: Downloaded newer image for memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

When I run `docker ps -a` I get no results

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

I don't run another containers at the moment. Why can't I run Memgraph Platform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to Memgraph Lab on port 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76927461/cant-connect-to-memgraph-lab-on-port-3000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I had a Next.js app running on port 3000 that prevented Docker from opening the port.

I used command `netstat -aon | find "3000"` (from question [Command line for looking at specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port)) to see if anything is connected to that port.